Quadratic inequalities; which values of $u$ makes $9y^2 + (u^2-4u-2)y +1 > 0$ true for all $y$?
For general quadratic,
$$ax^2+bx+c > 0.$$
If $a > 0$ and $b^2-4ac< 0$, does the above hold for all real values of $x$? Can this be applied to different formats of quadratic as well?
For example, consider,
$$9y^2 + (u^2-4u-2)y +1 > 0.$$
Here, I observed $a=9>0$. So
$$(u^2-4u-2)^2-4 \cdot 9<0$$
$$(u^2-4u-2)^2< 36,$$
so, $-6< (u^2-4u-2) <6$, which gave me $u ∈ (2-2\sqrt{3},2+2\sqrt{3}), u \neq 2$.
Is this approach correct?

To confirm, the problem is to find the values of $a$ such that $9y^2 + (a^2 - 4a - 2)y + 1 > 0$ holds for all $y$? Just FYI, using $a$ both in the problem, and as a shorthand for the coefficient of $y$, is confusing.

@TheoBendit Yes, the problem is infact to find out values of a for which inequality holds true. If variable a is confusing, you can use any other as per your wish. It would be great if you verified, and suggested my approach. Thanks.

Yeah, this work all looks solid.

Will the answer change if y=3^x? We are still again focused to find out range of 'u'(previously a) for which inequality holds true?

Yes, this will change things, simply because $y$ will range over the positive numbers, rather than all real numbers. You may get more values of $a$ that work. I would split into two cases: is the vertex $y^$ positive, or non-positive? For the $a$ where $y^ > 0$, your solution is correct. For the $a$ where $y^* \le 0$, you just want to verify that the quadratic, evaluated at $0$, comes out to be at least $0$. This is equivalent to the constant term, $1$, being positive, i.e. which happens always. Basically, you need to include all the $a$ such that $y^* \le 0$.

Resolve[ForAll[y, 9*y^2 + (u^2 - 4 u - 2)*y + 1 > 0], Reals] Mathematica shows the result is $2 \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)<u<2\lor 2<u<2 \left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)$


Quadratic inequalities; which values of $u$ makes $9y^2 + (u^2-4u-2)y +1 > 0$ true for all $y$?

Alternative approach:
Generally, the quadratic inequality $~x^2 + bx + c > 0~$ is solved by completing the square.
That is
$$\left( ~x + \frac{b}{2} ~\right)^2 + \left[ ~c - \frac{b^2}{4} ~\right] > 0.$$
Similarly, the inequality
$$9y^2 + (u^2-4u-2)y +1 > 0$$
can be re-written as
$$\left[ ~3y + \frac{u^2 - 4u - 2}{6} ~\right] ^2  + \left[ ~1 - \frac{( ~u^2 - 4u - 2 ~)^2}{36} ~\right] > 0. \tag1 $$
The inequality in (1) above will be true for all $~y~$ if and only if the RHS term is always positive.
So, the problem has been reduced to solving the inequality
$$1 - \frac{( ~u^2 - 4u - 2 ~)^2}{36} > 0 \iff $$
$$36 - (u^2 - 4u - 2)^2 > 0 \iff $$
$$[ ~6 - (u^2 - 4u - 2) ~] \times [ ~6 + (u^2 - 4u - 2) ~] > 0 \iff $$
$$[ ~-u^2 + 4u + 8 ~] \times [u^2 - 4u + 4~] > 0. \tag2 $$
The inequality in (2) above will hold if and only if both of the factors in (2) above are positive or both of the factors in (2) above are negative.
However, the second factor in (2) above, which equals $~(u - 2)^2,~$ can never be negative.  Therefore, the entire problem reduces to identifying those values of $~u~$ that make both of the factors in (2) above positive.

For the first factor in (2) above:
$$-u^2 + 4u + 8 > 0 \iff u^2 - 4u - 8 < 0 \iff $$
$$(u - 2)^2 - 12 < 0 \iff -2\sqrt{3} < (u - 2) < 2\sqrt{3} \iff $$
$$2 - 2\sqrt{3} < u < 2 + 2\sqrt{3}.$$
For the second factor in (2) above:
$$u^2 - 4u + 4 > 0 \iff (u - 2)^2 > 0 \iff u \neq 2.$$
Consolidating the analysis of both factors gives
$$[ ~2 - 2\sqrt{3} < u < 2 ~] ~~\text{or} ~~[ ~2 < u < 2 + 2\sqrt{3} ~].$$
